# Finding the invariant factors for the Rational Canonical Form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, jordan-normal-form

Say we are given the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A_{1,1} & A_{1,2} \\
0 & A_{2,2} \end{pmatrix}$$

and asked to find the Rational Canonical Form. Finding the characteristic polynomial is rather easy considering this is a block matrix. So we have $c_A(x) = \det(xI -A_{1,1})\det(xI-A_{2,2})=(x-2)^6(x-3)^2$.

So my questions are this:

1. Is there an easy way of computing the minimal polynomial for this matrix? I know it is $m_A(x) = (x-2)^4(x-3)^2$. However, explicitly computing all combinations of $(A-2I)^n(A-3I)^m$ for $1\leq n \leq 6$ and $1 \leq m \leq 2$ and seeing which smallest one gives us $0$ with a matrix this size (even in block form) seems tedious.
2. Given that minimal polynomial, how do we see that the invariant factors are $(x-2), (x-2),$ and $(x-2)^4(x-3)^2$?

Once this is done, the rational canonical form falls out immediately, but I'm unsure of how to show these two questions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: the more common name for rational-canonical form is Frobenius normal form. We don't need a tag for the former.

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks for the heads up. I didn't know the other name; now I do!

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$
R =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccc}
1 & 0& 0 &0& 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 &  0& 0& 0& 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
0  & 0 &0 &0& 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
0& 0 &0 &0& 0& 0 &1& 0 \\
0 &1& 0 &0 &0 &0 &0& 0 \\
0 &0& 1 &0 &0 &0& 0& 0 \\
0 &0& 0 &1 &0 &0& 0& 0 \\
0 &0& 0 &0 & 0 &0 &0 &1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$
then $R^2 = I$ and $RAR$ is in Jordan form